# comparison for maps does not produce correct result

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I have two hash maps finalOldCsv and finalNewCsv.These map stores values read from old and new csv.Below is my code to find out common rows,rows from only old csv and rows only from new csv.for small csv that consist of thousand of rows ,my code works fine.But when I try to execute the same on a csv of a million rows.it produces wrong result.code-

```
 private static void findDiff(LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> finalOldCsv,
            LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> finalNewCsv) {
        for(String test:finalOldCsv.keySet())
        {
        System.out.println("first row from old="+finalOldCsv.get(test));
        }
        for(String test1:finalNewCsv.keySet())
        {
        System.out.println("first row from new="+finalNewCsv.get(test1));

        }
         ArrayList<String>temp=new ArrayList<String>();
         for(String oldMatch : finalNewCsv.keySet())
         {
             if(oldMatch.contains(column[0]))
                 continue;
             else
             {
                 if (finalNewCsv.containsKey(oldMatch)&& finalOldCsv.containsKey(oldMatch))
                 {
                     System.out.println("Match Found");
                     writeCsv(writer,"Result/"+prefix+"_", oldMatch,"Common Rows");
                    temp.add(oldMatch);
                 }
             }
         }
         System.out.println("before old csv size="+finalOldCsv.size());
         for(String t:temp)
         {
         finalNewCsv.remove(t);
         finalOldCsv.remove(t);
         }
         System.out.println("after old csv size="+finalOldCsv.size());
         temp.clear();
         for(String newMatch : finalNewCsv.keySet())
           {
             if(newMatch.contains(column[0]))
            continue;
             else
             {
                 if (!finalOldCsv.containsKey(newMatch)&& finalNewCsv.containsKey(newMatch))
                 {
                 writeCsv(writer,"Result/"+prefix+"_", newMatch,"New Rows in New Table");
                 temp.add(newMatch);

                 }
             }

           }
         for(String t:temp)
         {
         finalNewCsv.remove(t);
         }
         temp.clear();
         System.out.println("finalOldCsv.keySet().size()"+finalOldCsv.keySet().size());
         for(String restFromOldTable:finalOldCsv.keySet())
         {
             if(restFromOldTable.contains(column[0]))
                 continue;
             else
                // if()
             writeCsv(writer,"Result/"+prefix+"_", restFromOldTable,"Rows from Old Table");
         }

    }
```

Comment: You say you get the wrong result for large data sets. How are the results wrong? What do you see? For smaller data sets have you tried a lot of combinations of data? If not then the size could well just be a coincidence.

Comment: don't make the data size tricks you, whether it's small or large it has nothing to do with the results, the problem is that what gives you the wrong results is simply doesn't exist in the small data size

Comment: Lets say if old and new csv have a same row,in this case code should print as "Common Rows" but it display "New Row in New table".

Comment: You have a test if it contains 'column[0]' (whatever that is - it's not declared in the code you show). Could the rows you are referring to fail that test?

Comment: "column[0]" is for ignoring header values.

Comment: Then I suggest you remove header values from both sets right at the start.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be quite a few logic errors in the code that I suggest you resolve and then repost:

1. your code iterates through the new key set and then tests if the entry is in the new key set. That makes no sense.
2. After you remove all the common rows you continue to test if keys you are considering are in both sets. There's no need for those tests.
3. In fact after you've removed all common rows you know all remaining rows are unique to one set or the other. You don't really need to test membership of the other sets at all.

So to end up with 3 sets - common, unique to old, unique to new, you really just need:

```
Set<String> common = oldMap.keySet().stream()
    .filter(k -> !k.equals(header))
    .filter(k -> newMap.keySet().contains(k)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<String> uniqueToOld = oldMap.keySet().stream()
    .filter(k -> !k.equals(header))
    .filter(k -> !common.contains(k)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<String> uniqueToNew = newMap.keySet().stream()
    .filter(k -> !k.equals(header))
    .filter(k -> !common.contains(k)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

That has the advantage of not changing the maps your method has been passed. Unless the method is explicitly supposed to be changing them then it's a bad idea to alter them as part of your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made this more complicated then it has to be.
For example, while you iterate over the `finalNewCsv` in the `if` statement you have this `finalNewCsv.containsKey(oldMatch)`, which is not necessary because it will be always `true`

The entire method can be simplified to this:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = oldMan.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = it.next();
        if (newMap.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            it.remove();
            commonEntries.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            newMap.remove(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

What this does is to add all similar keys in the `oldMap` and `newMap` to the `commonEntries` map. I'm not entirely sure if this is what the `findDiff()` is supposed to do (the method's name is misleading).